# CSS Conditional statements in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

I need to change the color of my div button when the the user is logged in.

[image]

Once the user is logged in i want him seeing the "Download button" in red, like the "play now" button in the img.

This is the code now:

```
      #play_buttons
      #instant_play.play_button
        %p
          = "#{t :"asiaplus.download_client"}"
        .button
          = "#{t :"asianplus.download_now"}" 
      #play_now.play_button
        %p
          %span.highlight
            = "#{t :"asiaplus.web_based"}"
          = "#{t :"asiaplus.live_dealer"}"
        %a{:href => "#{live_casino_ho_lobby_asia_path(:tab => current_tab, :locale => current_locale)}", :class => "button", :title => "#{t :'asiaplus.play_now'}", :id => "ho_roulette"}
          = "#{t :"asiaplus.play_now"}"
```

`.button` is the class for the button "Download now" on the left and `:id => "ho_roulette"` gives the style for the "Play now" button on the right.

Ok this is my solution to achieve the Download now button style like the Play Now button when the user is logged in:

```
       #play_buttons
     - if logged_in 
      #instant_play.play_button
        %p
          = "#{t :"asiaplus.download_client"}"
        .button
          = "#{t :"asianplus.download_now" :id => "ho_roulette"}" 
      #play_now.play_button
        %p
          %span.highlight
            = "#{t :"asiaplus.web_based"}"
          = "#{t :"asiaplus.live_dealer"}"
        %a{:href => "#{live_casino_ho_lobby_asia_path(:tab => current_tab, :locale => current_locale)}", :class => "button", :title => "#{t :'asiaplus.play_now'}", :id => "ho_roulette"}
          = "#{t :"asiaplus.play_now"}"
    - else 
      #instant_play.play_button
        %p
          = "#{t :"asiaplus.download_client"}"
        .button
          = "#{t :"asianplus.download_now"}" 
      #play_now.play_button
        %p
          %span.highlight
            = "#{t :"asiaplus.web_based"}"
          = "#{t :"asiaplus.live_dealer"}"
        %a{:href => "#{live_casino_ho_lobby_asia_path(:tab => current_tab, :locale => current_locale)}", :class => "button", :title => "#{t :'asiaplus.play_now'}", :id => "ho_roulette"}
          = "#{t :"asiaplus.play_now"}"
```

Basically i have used conditional statements adding `:id => "ho_roulette"` to my div button when the user is logged in.

Is this solution correct? i thought also i can use the status class active as other solution, but i did not want to touch my SASS file.

Comment: `= "#{t()}"` is the bad form for: `= t()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is good. Conditional CSS is the easiest solution.
You should dry it up though. Instead of having the whole thing in the if/else statement, simply do it for your `id`:

```
  #instant_play.play_button
    %p
      = t(:"asiaplus.download_client")
    .button
      = t(:"asianplus.download_now"), :id => ('ho_roulette' if logged_in)
  #play_now.play_button
    %p
      %span.highlight
        = t(:"asiaplus.web_based")
      = t(:"asiaplus.live_dealer")
    %a{:href => live_casino_ho_lobby_asia_path(:tab => current_tab, :locale => current_locale), :class => "button", :title => t(:'asiaplus.play_now'), :id => "ho_roulette"}
      = t(:"asiaplus.play_now")
```

### To consider:

- You should follow @apneadiving's advice to reformat your `t()`.
- @charleyc is 100% right with regards to having `id` unique. Consider using his solution and changing your SASS file... and your approach to your use of `id` tags to define CSS rules. States (like 'active' or 'ho_roulette') should *always* be CSS classes.

Comment: What is best to use inside the bracket : "" or ''? you have used '' but @charleyc use "" For example class => ('active', if logged_in) or class => ("active" if logged_in)

Comment: It is entirely up to you. I prefer to use single quotes everywhere I can and only use double when doing string interpolation. In most cases, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things I would revise about your solution:

1. HTML `id` tags should be unique, so you shouldn't have two different elements with the same ID.  You definitely want to use `class` instead.
2. You're repeating a whole lot of code here.  It would be much better to use the conditional inside of your tag, and take advantage of the fact that HAML ignores keys with `nil` values:

   ```
   play_buttons
     #instant_play.play_button
     %p
       = t :"asiaplus.download_client"
     .button
       = t :"asianplus.download_now", :class => ("active" if logged_in)
     #play_now.play_button
     %p
       %span.highlight
         = t :"asiaplus.web_based"
       = t :"asiaplus.live_dealer"
     = link_to t("asiaplus.play_now"), live_casino_ho_lobby_asia_path(:tab => current_tab, :locale => current_locale), :class => ["button", ("active" if logged_in)], :title => t('asiaplus.play_now'), :id => "ho_roulette"}
   ```

Comment: Even though I agree 100% with you, he said he didn't want to touch his css file.

Comment: i have not understoood why you repeat :id => "ho_roulette" at the end if you have already add :class => ["button", ("active" if logged_in)]

Comment: I added that because I'm assuming that he's using that `id` tag as an actual id for an element (e.g. for more styling or to trigger some Javascript).  If it's only being used for this particular styling effect then it can go away.